# Neo4j Cypher remove duplicate values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my Cypher query I return 2 columns:

```
RETURN  node.name, rootNode.name
```

This is values of the columns:

[image]

How to remove all records with Neo4j Cypher from `node.name` column if the value of this column is present in any of the `rooNode.name` column value?

**UPDATED**

This is my entire query:

```
@Query("CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes(\"skillAndTranslationLowerNames\", $namePattern) YIELD node, score " +
        "WHERE node.deleted = false " +
        "OPTIONAL MATCH (node)-[:ALIAS_FOR*]->(rootAliasOwner:Skill {deleted: false}) " +
        "WHERE NOT (rootAliasOwner)-[:ALIAS_FOR*]->(:Skill) " +
        "OPTIONAL MATCH (node)<-[:CONTAINS]-(translationOwner:Skill {deleted: false}) " +

        "OPTIONAL MATCH (translationOwner)-[:ALIAS_FOR*]->(rootTranslationOwner:Skill {deleted: false}) " +
        "WHERE NOT (rootTranslationOwner)-[:ALIAS_FOR*]->(:Skill) " +
        "WITH node, score, rootAliasOwner, coalesce(rootTranslationOwner, translationOwner) as rootTranslationOwner " +
        "WITH node, score, coalesce(rootAliasOwner, rootTranslationOwner) as rootNode " +

        "OPTIONAL MATCH (node)-[rNodeT:CONTAINS]->(nodeT:Translation {deleted: false}) WHERE ($iso6391 IS NOT null AND nodeT.iso6391 = $iso6391) " +
        "OPTIONAL MATCH (rootNode)-[rRootNodeT:CONTAINS]->(rootNodeT:Translation {deleted: false}) WHERE ($iso6391 IS NOT null AND rootNodeT.iso6391 = $iso6391) " +

        "RETURN DISTINCT node, rNodeT, nodeT, rootNode, rRootNodeT, rootNodeT, score " +
        "SKIP $page LIMIT $size")
```

for example I have the following result set:

```
"ecmascript-harmony"       null 
"ecmascript-8"             "ecmascript-2017"    
"ecmascript-2017"          null 
"ecmascript-next"          null 
"ecmascript-7"             "ecmascript-2016"    
"ecmascript-2016"          null 
"ecmascript-5"             null
```

I need to remove records where `rootNode` from resultset are present in the `node` column (in any row). In the example above this is `"ecmascript-2016"` and `"ecmascript-2017"`. So, I need to receive the following:

```
"ecmascript-harmony"       null 
"ecmascript-2017"          null 
"ecmascript-next"          null     
"ecmascript-2016"          null 
"ecmascript-5"             null
```

Comment: please give us your entire query and will help you figure it out. thanks.

Comment: thanks, I updated the question with an entire query

Comment: Are you concerned about merging them? If yes check APOC procedure for merging. https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/merge-nodes/

Comment: I need to remove records where rootNode from resultset are present in the node column.  I added an example to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trivial, but this should work:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("skillAndTranslationLowerNames", $namePattern) YIELD node, score
WHERE node.deleted = false
OPTIONAL MATCH (node)-[:ALIAS_FOR*]->(rootAliasOwner:Skill {deleted: false})
WHERE NOT (rootAliasOwner)-[:ALIAS_FOR*]->(:Skill)
OPTIONAL MATCH (node)<-[:CONTAINS]-(translationOwner:Skill {deleted: false})
OPTIONAL MATCH (translationOwner)-[:ALIAS_FOR*]->(rootTranslationOwner:Skill {deleted: false})
WHERE NOT (rootTranslationOwner)-[:ALIAS_FOR*]->(:Skill)
WITH node, score, rootAliasOwner, coalesce(rootTranslationOwner, translationOwner) as rootTranslationOwner
WITH node, score, coalesce(rootAliasOwner, rootTranslationOwner) as rootNode
OPTIONAL MATCH (node)-[rNodeT:CONTAINS]->(nodeT:Translation {deleted: false}) WHERE ($iso6391 IS NOT null AND nodeT.iso6391 = $iso6391)
OPTIONAL MATCH (rootNode)-[rRootNodeT:CONTAINS]->(rootNodeT:Translation {deleted: false}) WHERE ($iso6391 IS NOT null AND rootNodeT.iso6391 = $iso6391)
WITH DISTINCT node, rNodeT, nodeT, rootNode, rRootNodeT, rootNodeT, score SKIP $page LIMIT $size
WITH COLLECT({n: node, rNt: rNodeT, nT: nodeT, rN: rootNode, rRNT: rRootNodeT, rNet: rootNodeT, score: score}) AS data
WITH data, reduce(map = {}, record IN data | apoc.map.setEntry(map, record.n.name, true)) AS map
UNWIND data AS rec
WITH rec.n AS node, rec.rNt AS rNodeT, rec.nT AS nodeT, rec.rN AS rootNode, rec.rRNT AS rRootNodeT, rec.rNet AS rootNodeT, rec.score AS score, map WHERE apoc.map.get(map, rootNode.name, null) IS NULL
RETURN node, rNodeT, nodeT, rootNode, rRootNodeT, rootNodeT, score
```

Let's pay attention this part:

```
WITH DISTINCT node, rNodeT, nodeT, rootNode, rRootNodeT, rootNodeT, score 
SKIP $page LIMIT $size
WITH COLLECT({n: node, rNt: rNodeT, nT: nodeT, rN: rootNode, rRNT: rRootNodeT, rNet: rootNodeT, score: score}) AS data
WITH data, reduce(map = {}, record IN data | apoc.map.setEntry(map, record.n.name, true)) AS map
UNWIND data AS rec
WITH rec.n AS node, rec.rNt AS rNodeT, rec.nT AS nodeT, rec.rN AS rootNode, rec.rRNT AS rRootNodeT, rec.rNet AS rootNodeT, rec.score AS score, map WHERE apoc.map.get(map, rootNode.name, null) IS NULL
RETURN node, rNodeT, nodeT, rootNode, rRootNodeT, rootNodeT, score
```

Here, we are restricting the dataset to the required amount, after applying `SKIP` and `LIMIT`. Then we collect the data in a list, basically a list of maps. Then using `reduce` function we populate a map, with `name` property of the node as key, and its value is true. Then we unwind the above-created list, and filter the records, where `rootNode` `name` is present in the map. Finally, return the filtered records.

Try it out, it's not tested. And position `SKIP` and `LIMIT` according to your use-case.